# Substracting value from the string with a regular expression

Tags: regex, awk, grep

There is some log-file.

```
$> cat ./text
Tue, 28 Feb 2012 15:43:20 407a3f8bbf704e41bef1f4c0ac24f310 FAILED
Tue, 2012 15:45:10 525b13aed6094417a56fd7bc67a10ad7 FAILED
Tue, 28 Feb 2012 15:47:08 ae3e2dc3e5b14d0eb7338ab308a32c8e
Tue, Feb 2012 15:52:26 18486cbede4e4cb4bee931bf29823dda FAILED
Tue, 28 Feb 2012 15:54:17 3c96983a68dd4c5e968dcad512bf77e9 FAILED
Tue, Feb 2012 15:56:30 2191e5260aa44a2a8997c47d710d6fbb FAILED
Tue, 28 Feb 2012 15:58:25 083fc56361414695b4e5cf54f8c57a9e FAILED
28 Feb 2012 16:01:55 5cbad64d2d62429c97ed7fdf98087c44 FAILED
Tue, 28 Feb 2012 16:03:37 a0d33b998b8247ffbecb984198453c0b
28 Feb 2012 16:05:32 cf9c1893e8b64aa89636a8cfeff56cf2 FAILED
Tue, 28 Feb 2012 16:06:53 027d99f7fa68436d9000661a7af07e2a PASSED
```

It's easy to get all that hex values with `grep`.

```
$> grep --only-matching --perl-regex "[0-9a-f]{32}" ./text
407a3f8bbf704e41bef1f4c0ac24f310
525b13aed6094417a56fd7bc67a10ad7
ae3e2dc3e5b14d0eb7338ab308a32c8e
18486cbede4e4cb4bee931bf29823dda
3c96983a68dd4c5e968dcad512bf77e9
2191e5260aa44a2a8997c47d710d6fbb
083fc56361414695b4e5cf54f8c57a9e
5cbad64d2d62429c97ed7fdf98087c44
a0d33b998b8247ffbecb984198453c0b
cf9c1893e8b64aa89636a8cfeff56cf2
027d99f7fa68436d9000661a7af07e2a
```

But how can I do it with `awk`?

So actual question is: how can I substract some value, that matching some regular expression, fro, a given string? For example, on some line of `awk`-source file I have $0 value, which is actually the whole string like `"Tue, Feb 2012 15:56:30 2191e5260aa44a2a8997c47d710d6fbb FAILED"`. I'm looking for some `awk` command to get hex value somehow like:

```
 hex = command_name( $0, "[0-9a-f]{32}" )
```

And `hex` will be equal to `2191e5260aa44a2a8997c47d710d6fbb`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why you need awk when its perfectly extract-able by grep?

Comment: @Shiplu maybe he wants to do further text processing on the string in awk without creating a chain of pipelines to do what awk can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use match() for this (gawk may be required for --re-interval):

```
$ gawk --re-interval '{ match($0, /[0-9a-fA-F]{32}/,arr); print arr[0]; }' testdata 
407a3f8bbf704e41bef1f4c0ac24f310
525b13aed6094417a56fd7bc67a10ad7
ae3e2dc3e5b14d0eb7338ab308a32c8e
18486cbede4e4cb4bee931bf29823dda
3c96983a68dd4c5e968dcad512bf77e9
2191e5260aa44a2a8997c47d710d6fbb
083fc56361414695b4e5cf54f8c57a9e
5cbad64d2d62429c97ed7fdf98087c44
a0d33b998b8247ffbecb984198453c0b
cf9c1893e8b64aa89636a8cfeff56cf2
027d99f7fa68436d9000661a7af07e2a
```

Comment: This answer, the original question and most of the other answers assume that the hex number in the data will be exactly 32 characters without ensuring that it is. One way to do that: `/(^|[^[:xdigit:]])[[:xdigit:]]{32}([^[:xdigit:]]|$)`

Answer (score 0):

The original `awk` program does not support back-references in regex-replace. If you're lucky and have access to GNU awk you can use the `sub()` function to extract parts of a string. In theory it works like this:

```
hex = sub(/^.* ([0-9a-fA-F]+) .*$/, "\1");
```

Since I don't have GNU awk at my hands at the moment you'll have to play around to find the correct syntax (e. g. `"\1"` vs. `"\\1"`, `+` vs `{32,32}`, and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try GNU extension `gensub()`

```
$ awk --re-interval '{print gensub(/^.*([0-9a-f]{32}).*$/,"\\1","")}' text
407a3f8bbf704e41bef1f4c0ac24f310
525b13aed6094417a56fd7bc67a10ad7
ae3e2dc3e5b14d0eb7338ab308a32c8e
18486cbede4e4cb4bee931bf29823dda
3c96983a68dd4c5e968dcad512bf77e9
2191e5260aa44a2a8997c47d710d6fbb
083fc56361414695b4e5cf54f8c57a9e
5cbad64d2d62429c97ed7fdf98087c44
a0d33b998b8247ffbecb984198453c0b
cf9c1893e8b64aa89636a8cfeff56cf2
027d99f7fa68436d9000661a7af07e2a
```

Answer (score 0):

non-GNU awk answer

```
awk '
  {
    for (i=NF; i>0; i--)
      if (length($i)==32 && ! match($i,/[^0-9a-fA-F]/)) {
        hexvalue = $i
        break  # if you only expect one per line
      }
    print hexvalue    # or do something else
  }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work or you:

```
awk --re-interval -vRS='[0-9a-fA-F]{32}' 'RT{print RT}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If your log file is consistently structured like the sample shown:

```
awk '{print $6}' ./text
```